Why does navigating to a path with double slash result 404?
In routes/api/[...url].ts I have this file:
import { Handlers } from "$fresh/server.ts";
export const handler: Handlers = {
  GET(_req, ctx) {
    return new Response(ctx.url.href);
  },
};

If I navigate to localhost:8000/api/A/B, it works fine. In my understanding, the filename [...url].ts should be correct, and a URL with double slash is valid, so I expect localhost:8000/api/A//B should work as well. But it results with 404. Why is that the case?
My goal is to build a CORS proxy, so there should be a double slash in the URL, e.g. http://localhost:8001/api/https://example.com/

If the slashes should be within a path segment, rather than indicating the boundary of the segment, they must be escaped.

I understand that it should be escaped. But I wonder why it doesn't work?

Upgrading Fresh to 1.6.8 solves the status code problem, but the URL is still processed. Instead of using ctx.url.href, use req.url to get the raw URL. ctx is a object from Fresh with interface FreshContext, while req is the native object with interface Request.
